# how do i make it so when i click on a button with the items selected from the option menu, a label will display

Tags: python, tkinter

how do i make it so when I click on a button with the items selected from the option menu, a label will display saying "you have ordered (the item selected from the option menu) and (the other item)"

```
  food = ['Pizza','Burger','Nachos', 'French Toast']
drinks = ['Pepsi','Lemonade','Tea', 'Aperitivo Spritz']

def order_menu(self):

        self.myFrame2.destroy()
        self.myFrame4 = Frame(root)
        self.myFrame4.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)

        self.tkvar = StringVar(self.myFrame4)
        self.tkvar.set("Food")
        self.tkvar.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(self.tkvar.get()))

        self.tkvar2 = StringVar(self.myFrame4)
        self.tkvar2.set("Drinks")
        self.tkvar2.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(self.tkvar2.get()))

        self.foodMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar, *food, command = self.callback)
        self.foodMenu.place(x = 160, y = 110)

        self.drinkMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar2, *drinks, command = self.callback)
        self.drinkMenu.place(x = 385, y = 110)

        self.order_btn78 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\orderb.png')
        self.order_btn = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.order_btn78, command = self.callback, bd = 0)
        self.order_btn.place(x = 302, y = 160)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
from tkinter import *


class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()

        self.menu_var = StringVar(self)
        self.menu = OptionMenu(self, self.menu_var, *['Pizza','Burger','Nachos', 'French Toast'])
        self.menu.pack(pady=10)

        self.info_label = Label(self, text="")
        self.info_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.btn = Button(self, text="SHOW", command=self.callback)
        self.btn.pack()

    def callback(self):
        self.info_label.configure(text=self.menu_var.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will update as soon as you select the menu.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def set_food(*args):
    lbl_1.config(text="Food: "+var1.get())
def set_drink(*args):
    lbl_2.config(text="Drink: "+var2.get())

food = ['Pizza','Burger','Nachos', 'French Toast']
drinks = ['Pepsi','Lemonade','Tea', 'Aperitivo Spritz']
var1=StringVar()
var2=StringVar()
var1.set("Food")
var2.set("Drink")
Label(root,text="Food").place(x=10,y=15)
Label(root,text="Drinks").place(x=10,y=55)
OptionMenu(root,var1,*food).place(x=50,y=10)
OptionMenu(root,var2,*drinks).place(x=50,y=50)
var1.trace("w",set_food)
var2.trace("w",set_drink)

Label(root,text="Chosen:").place(x=30,y=90)

lbl_1=Label(root)
lbl_1.place(x=50,y=120)
lbl_2=Label(root)
lbl_2.place(x=50,y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

However, if you do want the buttons:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def set_mwnu():
    lbl_2.config(text="Drink: "+var2.get())
    lbl_1.config(text="Food: "+var2.get())

food = ['Pizza','Burger','Nachos', 'French Toast']
drinks = ['Pepsi','Lemonade','Tea', 'Aperitivo Spritz']
var1=StringVar()
var2=StringVar()
var1.set("Food")
var2.set("Drink")
Label(root,text="Food").place(x=10,y=15)
Label(root,text="Drinks").place(x=10,y=55)
OptionMenu(root,var1,*food).place(x=50,y=10)
OptionMenu(root,var2,*drinks).place(x=50,y=50)
Button(root,command=set_menu()).place(x=30,y=90)

Label(root,text="Chosen:").place(x=30,y=120)

lbl_1=Label(root)
lbl_1.place(x=50,y=150)
lbl_2=Label(root)
lbl_2.place(x=50,y=180)

root.mainloop()
```